# Iterate through integers to find mod in if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I make the below code neater

```
if integer % 2 == 0 or integer % 3 == 0 or ... integer % 9 == 0:
```

edit:

I am trying to check whether the variable `integer` is  **fully** (i.e. there is no remainder after the division) divisible by any of the following integers: `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. And I was wondering whether there is a better way to write that if statement.

Comment: The question is unclear, at least to me. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As a small optimization note: You can drop 2,3,4: If it's divisible by 8, it's divisible by 2 and 4; if it's divisible by 9, it's divisible by 3. Technically, you can drop 6 as well; if it's divisible by 8 and 9, it's divisible by 6. So you just need to check [4,7,8,9].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(integer % x == 0 for x in range(2, 10)):
```

Comment: follow-up q. How would you shorten this? `primes = [x for x in range(2,1001) if x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 != 0 and x % 4 != 0 and x % 5 != 0 and x % 6 != 0 and x % 7 != 0 and x % 8 != 0 and x % 9 != 0]`

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: You'd use `all` instead of `any`. Note that your tests are redundant: `x % 2` cannot be zero if `x % 8` isn't zero. If you want to generate a list of primes <1001 in this (inefficient) fashion you need to test for divisibility by the primes <= 31, i.e, (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29). Note that your algorithm _won't_ include the numbers you're dividing by in your `primes` list.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: Here's a modified example of your code that makes a list of the primes < 11**2. `pr=(2,3,5,7); primes=[x for x in range(2,121) if x in pr or all(x%i for i in pr)]`

Comment: what is i standing there for in that comprehension?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: `i` takes on the values in the tuple `pr`, in other words, the primes less than the square root of 121.